# using java.awt classes in android

Tags: android, awt

i'm currently trying to use the library LLaTeXMath in an android app. The problem is, many functions want Arguments or have return values from the java.awt Package. So far, I've encountered `Color`, `Insets`, `Image`.
For example the Method `TeXFormula.createBufferedImage()` requires 2 `Color`instances and returns an `Image`. How can i provide the arguments and use the return value?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. The only class from awt you can use in android is [java.awt.font](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/awt/font/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

ok forget it, i found out, there is an android version of jlatexmath. I just have to figure out, how to use it, since it doesn't come as a jar file and is not a gradle project, but that doesn't belong here